# Using VS 2019 Worker Template, a Background service is quitting

Tags: c#, .net-core, system.threading.channels

Using .Net core 3.1 and the Visual Studio 2019 Worker Template.

I followed example code found online. The Background task MessageReadingService reads a message from Amazon SQS. The message is written to a ChannelReader.  The Background task MessageProcessingService, reads the message from ChannelReader and processes it.

This works as expected for the first message.  Setting a breakpoint in MessageProcessingService stops after the first message but never again.  I assume the task is quitting.

My code follows the pattern of the example code (which works fine).  Any suggestions would be helpful.  Maybe a debugging technique?  Thanks!

```
 public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                {
                    services.Configure<AwsServicesConfiguration>(hostContext.Configuration.GetSection("AWS"));

                    services.AddAWSService<IAmazonSQS>();
                    services.AddTransient<IMessageProcessor, AwsMessageProcessor>();
                    services.AddSingleton<ISqsMessageChannel, SqsMessageChannel>();
                    services.AddSingleton<ISqsMessageDeleter, SqsMessageDeleter>();
                     services.AddSingleton<ISqsMessageQueue, SqsMessageQueue>();
                    services.AddHostedService<MessageReadingService>();
                    services.AddHostedService<MessageProcessingService>();

                });
    }
    
}

// Message Reading Service
 
  public class MessageReadingService : BackgroundService
    {
        private readonly ILogger<MessageReadingService> _logger;
        private readonly ISqsMessageChannel _sqsMessageChannel;
        private readonly string _queueUrl;
         private static AmazonSQSClient sqs;

        public long ReceivesAttempted { get; private set; }
        public long MessagesReceived { get; private set; }

        public MessageReadingService(
            ILogger<MessageReadingService> logger,
            ISqsMessageQueue sqsMessageQueue,
            IOptions<AwsServicesConfiguration> options,
            ISqsMessageChannel sqsMessageChannel)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            MComSettingsManager mComSettingsManager = new MComSettingsManager();
            BasicAWSCredentials awsCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(Access_Key,Secret_Key);
            AmazonSQSConfig amazonSQSConfig = new AmazonSQSConfig();
            amazonSQSConfig.ServiceURL = ServiceURL;
            sqs = new AmazonSQSClient(awsCredentials, amazonSQSConfig);
           
            _sqsMessageChannel = sqsMessageChannel;
            _queueUrl = options.Value.QueueUrl;

            _logger.LogInformation($"Reading from {_queueUrl}");

        }


    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Started queue reading service.");

            var receiveMessageRequest = new ReceiveMessageRequest
            {
                AttributeNames = new List<string>() { "Body" },
                MaxNumberOfMessages = 10,  
                QueueUrl = _queueUrl,
       
                WaitTimeSeconds = 5
            };

            while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                ReceivesAttempted++;

                var receiveMessageResponse =
                    await sqs.ReceiveMessageAsync(receiveMessageRequest, stoppingToken);

                if (receiveMessageResponse.HttpStatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK &&
                    receiveMessageResponse.Messages.Any())
                {
                    MessagesReceived += receiveMessageResponse.Messages.Count;

                    _logger.LogInformation("Received {MessageCount} messages from the queue.",
                        receiveMessageResponse.Messages.Count);

                    await _sqsMessageChannel.WriteMessagesAsync(receiveMessageResponse.Messages, stoppingToken);
                }
                else if (receiveMessageResponse.HttpStatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation("No messages received. Attempting receive again in 1 minute.",
                        receiveMessageResponse.Messages.Count);
                    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), stoppingToken);
                   
                }
                else if (receiveMessageResponse.HttpStatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    _logger.LogError("Unsuccessful response from AWS SQS.");
                }
            }

            _sqsMessageChannel.TryCompleteWriter();
        }

 
 
 
 public class MessageProcessingService : BackgroundService
    {
        private readonly ILogger<MessageProcessingService> _logger;
        private readonly ISqsMessageChannel _sqsMessageChannel;
        private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
        private readonly MySqlConnection conn;

        public MessageProcessingService(
            ILogger<MessageProcessingService> logger,
            ISqsMessageChannel sqsMessageChannel,
            IServiceProvider serviceProvider
           )
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _sqsMessageChannel = sqsMessageChannel;
            _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
            conn = new MySqlConnection(GaaSManager.ConnectionString);
            conn.Open();
        }

        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                await foreach (var message in _sqsMessageChannel.Reader.ReadAllAsync(stoppingToken))
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation("Read message to process from channel.");

                    using var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope();

                    var messageProcessor = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IMessageProcessor>();

                    await messageProcessor.ProcessOperationsFromMessageAsync(message, conn, stoppingToken);
                }
            }
            
        }
    }
 
 
 
 
 
 public interface IMessageProcessor
    {
        Task ProcessOperationsFromMessageAsync(Message message, MySqlConnection conn,CancellationToken cancellationToken = default);
    }
 
 public class AwsMessageProcessor : IMessageProcessor
    {

        private readonly ISqsMessageDeleter _sqsMessageDeleter;


        public AwsMessageProcessor(ISqsMessageDeleter sqsMessageDeleter)
        {

            _sqsMessageDeleter = sqsMessageDeleter;

        }

        public async Task ProcessOperationsFromMessageAsync(Message message, MySqlConnection conn, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
            PayloadManager payloadMgr = PayloadManager.Instance;


            Class1 object1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Class1>(message.Body);



            if (object1.field1 == VALUE)
            {
                // store for later processing
                Class2 object2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Class2>(object1.JsonWork);

                ProcessObject(object2,conn);

               
            }
            else
            {
                SaveClass3(object1,conn);
            }
            
            await _sqsMessageDeleter.DeleteMessageAsync(message);
        }




      
        public void ProcessObject(Class2 object2, MySqlConnection conn)
        {
            
            Working MySQL Code
                   
                
        }

    
        public void SaveClass3(Class3 object3, MySqlConnection conn)
        {
            
                Working MySQL Code

        }


    }
```

Comment: Could you provide code for `MessageReadingService` and `MessageProcessingService`?

Comment: Added requested code. Tried to stub out code that was not relevant to the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to implement `while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)` pattern in `MessageProcessingService` as otherwise `_sqsMessageChannel.Reader.ReadAllAsync` is called once and service is stopped.

Comment: Thanks! I added "while loop" but it still processes one message and exits. When more messages are received, the MessageProcessingService is not called at all. I can see that six messages are read and put in the Channel. But none are processed after the first time around.

Comment: Then you probably have multiple issues here, you need to check each component in depth

Comment: Yes. Coder for 35 years but never worked with background processes. I'll have to find some docs on the topic. Thanks!